# How to loop an array of objects using Kusto Query Language

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

already I'm facing a problem which is the inability to loop an array of objects using Kusto Query Language.
The Table (Events) is under this form.

| Event | Entities |
| --- | --- |
| Ev1 | [{"$id":"1","Name":"Ilyes Tab","UPNSuffix":"gmail.com","Type":"account"}, {"$id":"2","Name":"John Smith","UPNSuffix":"gmail.com","Type":"account"}] |
| Ev2 | [{"$id":"3","Name":"william Red","UPNSuffix":"gmail.com","Type":"account"}, {"$id":"5","Name":"Steve Smith","UPNSuffix":"gmail.com","Type":"account"}, {"$id":"8","Name":"Reshald M","UPNSuffix":"gmail.com","Type":"account"}] |
| Ev3 | [{"$id":"4","Name":"Fred Stalone","UPNSuffix":"gmail.com","Type":"account"}] |

I want to loop into each object of the column "Entities" then I'm going to save the Names of these entities within a new column which will be under this form.

| AllEntities |
| --- |
| Ilyes Tab |
| John Smith |
| william Red |
| Steve Smith |
| Reshald M |
| Fred Stalone |

Already I have worked around this problem by looping manually into each object, this is the code I managed to develop.

```
Events 
| project Event, 
 Entities1=tostring(parse_json(Entities)[0].Name) 
,Entities2=tostring(parse_json(Entities)[1].Name) 
,Entities3=tostring(parse_json(Entities)[2].Name) 
,Entities4=tostring(parse_json(Entities)[3].Name), 
| project AllEntities = coalesce(Entities1,Entities2,Entities3,Entities4) 
| summarize count() by AllEntities
```

I'm asking if anyone can offer me a solution or a function to make my loop automatically.

Comment: Per SO guidelines - please remove the images and provide the data in textual format (datatable / CSV / markdown table)

Comment: The code makes no sense, especially the use of *coalesce*. What is you end game here?

Comment: Hi david, thank you for your response. you will find here my table. https://storage19985645.blob.core.windows.net/data2/Classeur.csv

Comment: . And the required results?

Comment: Also, are you sure that *Entities* is of *string* type, and not *dynamic*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KQL is a declarative language, similarly to SQL, and declarative languages do not use control flow commands (e.g., if, goto or loop), but provide special syntax / operators / functions that deal with complex types.

KQL provides the following operators:

- [mv-expand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator)
- [mv-apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator)

```
datatable(Event:string, Entities:string)
[ 
    'Ev1' ,'[{"$id":"1","Name":"Ilyes Tab","UPNSuffix":"gmail.com","Type":"account"}, {"$id":"2","Name":"John Smith","UPNSuffix":"gmail.com","Type":"account"}]'
   ,'Ev2' ,'[{"$id":"3","Name":"william Red","UPNSuffix":"gmail.com","Type":"account"}, {"$id":"5","Name":"Steve Smith","UPNSuffix":"gmail.com","Type":"account"}, {"$id":"8","Name":"Reshald M","UPNSuffix":"gmail.com","Type":"account"}]'
   ,'Ev3' ,'[{"$id":"4","Name":"Fred Stalone","UPNSuffix":"gmail.com","Type":"account"}]'
]    
| mv-expand parse_json(Entities)
| project AllEntities = tostring(Entities.Name)
```

| AllEntities |
| --- |
| Ilyes Tab |
| John Smith |
| william Red |
| Steve Smith |
| Reshald M |
| Fred Stalone |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA52SXUvDMBSG7wv9D4cgdIU42KYgAy+8qKDgkHVejSFZc7Zm5KM0Wd1Q/7ups4ZddslNeHl5eA45nDl/1xIHWYPaTa2rhd5SyLQTTqD9C9I4WkIcgT9J1owSoMnyk1wJTqZkRCiZMYX++SSPaGHB1j56e53l+81GHHy+VUzIYWGUzxfHqq2yojB77cg3hQ40DqBnU2rIlXBlD9Iq+TWk3nB8ZjgJ4A8hpWAK5sgvcrwNqNxhg70lA+ouoOZoSyY5vFw27eRs2pvAfayRQ+6YNBp7olftX8fRF6jmGg8V0xwqVlt831mjB916pG2jqs0OCwcPUnY53IMzp9X57w5bqfQHn15X7XECAAA=)

Comment: Thank you sir, I am most satisfied with your response which totally covered my needs.

Comment: Great to hear. Please close the loop by accepting the answer.

Comment: It's done David